# How to know that a List has a particular index?

Tags: java, arraylist

There is a `List` :

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(300);
l.add(3070);
if (l.get(8) == null) System.out.println("null"); else System.out.println("something else");
```

At runtime I got ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception , so how to know that a particular index exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list size and minus 1 to find out the last index

Answer (score 3):

Simple; you call: `list.size()`.

Similarly to arrays, you want to **check** the length of your list before accessing an index.

If you don't do that; then you found the "answer" yourself already: trying to access an invalid index results in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown at you.

And don't get me wrong: but the **real** answer here: study the concepts you intend to use.

You seem to have some ideas how "lists" work in general (maybe based on similar concepts in other programming languages). But that is not how you write code: you don't assume. You turn to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for the things you want to use; and you study that. Or you read the corresponding [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)!

Answer (score 1):

check  the size of the list by using [ArrayList.size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) method. there can't be index more than `size-1`

Answer (score 1):

You should add check for size of `ArrayList` like below code:

```
if (l.size()>8 && l.get(8) == null) 
System.out.println("null"); 
else 
System.out.println("something else");
```

Use && operatior to add mutlipal condition in if clause.